# Bootloader unlock failure "Command not allowed" of a Huawei Honor 6x

Tags: bootloader, huawei-honor-6

I have followed all instructions to unlock my Huawei bootloader, until the last instruction in the command prompt.

Some maybe useful information:

- My computer runs windows 10
- My phone is a Huawei Honor 6x (title)
- I am using a charging cable to connect my phone to my computer

What I did so far:

1. Registered a Huawei account, and got my access code
2. Turned on USB debugging
3. Connected my phone and computer with a charging cable
4. Ran adb and fastboot
5. Opened Windows Powershell (I couldn't find command in the adb folder) and typed the following commands:

   - adb reboot bootlader
   - fastboot oem unlock 2**************1

It produces an error message that says:
[image: failed, command not allowed]

Also, my phone should say "unlocked", but it still says "locked".

Any ideas on why the command is not allowed?

Comment: After turning on developer settings did you turn on `Allow OEM unlocking` option?

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried that now, and it seems to be working fine! One last question, do you know any good softwares to be able to root my phone?

Comment: Search for Magisk and see if it is compatible with your phone (most likely it should be). You should also try to flash TWRP recovery first.

Comment: Uhh... What's the point of unlocking your bootloader in the first place? That's right, installing custom recoveries and rooting from there.

Comment: You can try:
fastboot oem get-bootinfo to make sure that it is unlocked or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Huawei has completely terminate the unlock code application service on July 25th, 2018.

You can refer to the following [link](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/community/details/Unlock-CODE-Bootloader-Honor-5C/topicId_117917/) where Huawei has officially mentioned it.